# How to match a string that doesn't contains a word before a match string?

Tags: c#, regex

Reading through stack overflow examples i couldn't find a working solution for the below test case.

I need to match a pattern being tested against a list of strings..

the pattern should match if word1 exist, but word2 doesn't exist before it.
Any character can exist in between.

Examples:
pattern - match if word `tty_osc` exist and `mov_osc` doesn't exist anywhere before it.

1. `abd.defg.mov_osc.ccr.tty_osc.val` - doesn't match... `tty_osc` exist but `mov_osc` also exist before `tty_osc`
2. `abd.defg.ccr.tty_osc.val` - match - `tty_osc` exist, no `mov_osc` before

I've tried the following negative lookbehind regex - `(?<!mov_osc).*tty_osc`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of what you have you have tried so far. Even better if the examples you have provided in your question were included in the sample code.

Comment: You need to perform two tests.  One to check if mov_osc is not before tty_osc and then 2nd test to check if tty_osc does exist.

Comment: Move the `.*` inside of the negative look behind.  It doesn't work because it's matching everything before tty_osc and then looking for mov_osc before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead  to assert what is on the right is not your forbidden word followed by the accepted word.

```
^(?!.*?\bmov_osc\b.*?\btty_osc\b).*?\btty_osc\b.*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L8puAF/1)

Comment: FYI your demo is using PHP which might not behave the same as C#.

Comment: @juharr It will work the same in C#. Just this way, the whole string will get matched, not just the `tty_osc` string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean in general you should use a regular expression tester that matches the engine being using.

Comment: @juharr That is a fair point, it works in C# as well. If the string should be matched until the accepted word then this pattern could be `^(?!.*?\bmov_osc\b.*?\btty_osc\b).*?\btty_osc\b`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `.*` inside of the negative look behind  `(?<!mov_osc.*)tty_osc`.  Otherwise it will match everything before tty_osc and the negative look behind would just check against the beginning of the string.

[RegexStorm.Net Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!mov_osc.*%29tty_osc&i=abd.defg.mov_osc.ccr.tty_osc.val%0D%0Aabd.defg.ccr.tty_osc.val)